# Change div's content after clicking on a link using Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

My div contains a PHP function having an sql query which fetch latest threads from `threads` table. The structure of my page is something like this;

```
Section # 1 --- Link 1
Section # 2 --- Link 2
Section # 3 --- Link 3
```

What I want to do is to make it so like when `Link 1` is clicked it shows the latest threads from `Section 1`, and when `Link 3` is clicked then it shows latest threads of `Section 3`.

PLEASE NOTE: I know that I can use slidetoggle() jQuery function to show and hide div, but I want to make it so that WHEN link is clicked THEN runs the sql query to show latest threads. I'm using the following jQuery;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {
        $('a[id^="forum_name"]').on('click', function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            var fid = $(this).attr("fid");
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: 'latest_threads.php?fid='+fid,
                dataType: 'json', 
                success: function (data)
                {
                    $("#forum_threads_"+fid).html(data).stop().slideToggle("fast");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

My PHP file `latest_threads.php` has the following code;

```
<?php
define("IN_MYBB", 1);
require_once "./global.php";

if ($mybb->input['fid'] != "")
{
    require_once MYBB_ROOT."inc/functions.php";
    $fid = intval($mybb->input['fid']);
    $forum['forum_threads'] = kalachi_forum_threads($fid);
}
?>
```

and My HTML is like;

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="forum_name" fid="{$forum['fid']}" title="See latest threads of this section.">{$forum['threads']}</a>
<div id="forum_threads_{$forum['fid']}" style="display: none;">{$forum['forum_threads']}</div>
```

But it doesn't works, please help!

Comment: waht error do are you getting?

Comment: No error, it actually doesn't fetching the latest threads and showing in the div id I mentioned.

Comment: You'll have to use AJAX to do what you want. jQuery has very nice AJAX support.

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit more, DampeS8N?

Comment: so, do you know about ajax ? your response from php is shown in your  console

Comment: I've very limited knowledge in ajax, sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('a[id^="forum_name"]').on('click', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var fid = $(this).attr("fid");
        $.ajax(
        {
            type : "post",
            dataType: "html",
            url : "misc.php?action=forum_threads&fid="+fid,
            cache: false,
            success : function(response)
            {
                $("#forum_threads_"+fid).stop().slideToggle("fast").html(response);
            }
        });
  });
});
```

### PHP:

```
<?php
define("IN_MYBB", 1);
require_once "./global.php";

if ($mybb->input['fid'] != "")
{
    require_once MYBB_ROOT."inc/functions.php";
    $fid = intval($mybb->input['fid']);
    echo $forum['forum_threads'] = kalachi_forum_threads($fid);
    exit;
}
?>
```

### In HTML:

Change the last line to this:

`<div id="forum_threads_{$forum['fid']}"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

You're not outputting your response as far as I can see.

Try something like this:

```
...
$forum['forum_threads'] = kalachi_forum_threads($fid);
echo $forum['forum_threads']
exit();
...
```

I added the *echo* line to output the actual response back to your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [**Ajax**](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) tutorial.

But in your case, you should know, the `data` that you are showing in your `div` in this part of your code :

```
success: function (data)
{
   $("#forum_threads_"+fid).html(data).stop().slideToggle("fast");
}
```

is the response of your php code.

Your php response is any output of your php code, it can be a simple `echo 'something'` or a html code, or including a html file etc.

generete a html code or include a html file in your php code, anything that you want to show in your div.

**Note:** always put a `die()` or `exit()` in the end of your php code.

This is a simple example :

**HTML** :

```
<div id="c1" onclick="javascript:loadcontent(1);">click</div><br>
<div id="c2" onclick="javascript:loadcontent(2);">click</div><br>
<div id="c1" onclick="javascript:loadcontent(3);">click</div><br/
```

**Javascript (jquery)** :

```
<script>
    function loadcontent(id) {
        $.post("yourphp.php", {id: id}, function(data) {
            if (data) {
                $("#c" + id).html(data);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**PHP - yourphp.php** :

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id'];
require 'filename'.$id.".html";
die;
?>
```

Then you must create 3 html  files with names : **filename1.html** , **filename2.html** , **filename3.html**
and put any content in them that you want to show in your divs with id c1,c2 or c3 .

Thats it

Comment: I didn't understand, can you please edit the code I provided and show an example, please?

Comment: let me know about the result

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Ali :)